# Nullpoint exception when startup JDeveloper 12.1.3 with SOA suite

Tags: ide, soa, jdeveloper

Any one met exceptions below when startup JDeveloper 12.1.3 with SOA suite ? this lead to I can not save the workspace, very bad. actually, I was wondering if there is anyone like JDeveloper, but I have to use it. :(

JDeveloper version: Build JDEVADF_12.1.3.0.0_GENERIC_140521.1008.S

Jdk version: java version "1.7.0_80"

stack trace as below:

       `SEVERE: 
    javax.naming.NamingException [Root exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]
        at oracle.adf.share.jndi.ContextImpl.throwNamingException(ContextImpl.java:671)
        at oracle.adf.share.jndi.ContextImpl.saveDocument(ContextImpl.java:968)
        at oracle.adf.share.jndi.ContextImpl.save(ContextImpl.java:986)
        at oracle.adf.share.dt.ConnectionNsChangeListener.refreshInternal(ConnectionNsChangeListener.java:242)
        at oracle.adf.share.dt.ConnectionNsChangeListener.refresh(ConnectionNsChangeListener.java:180)
        at oracle.adf.share.dt.ConnectionNsChangeListener.objectAdded(ConnectionNsChangeListener.java:43)
        ...

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.jdevimpl.jps.JpsConfigUtilsImpl.getDefaultJpsContext(JpsConfigUtilsImpl.java:722)
        at oracle.jdevimpl.jps.JpsConfigUtilsImpl.getCredentialStoreLocation(JpsConfigUtilsImpl.java:1407)
        at oracle.adf.share.dt.security.providers.jps.CSFDTCredentialStore.checkInitCSFStore(CSFDTCredentialStore.java:333)
        at oracle.adf.share.dt.security.providers.jps.CSFDTCredentialStore.fetchCredential(CSFDTCredentialStore.java:588)
        at oracle.adf.share.dt.security.providers.jps.CSFDTCredentialStore.fetchCredential(CSFDTCredentialStore.java:578)
        at oracle.adf.share.security.credentialstore.CredentialStore.fetchCredential(CredentialStore.java:187)
        at oracle.adf.share.jndi.CredentialStoreHelper.fetchCredential(CredentialStoreHelper.java:104)
        at oracle.adf.share.jndi.ReferenceStoreHelper.saveCredentialsInternal(ReferenceStoreHelper.java:520)
        at oracle.adf.share.jndi.ReferenceStoreHelper.saveCredentials(ReferenceStoreHelper.java:476)
        at oracle.adf.share.jndi.ContextImpl.saveDocument(ContextImpl.java:957)
        ... 123 more`

Comment: Have you tried running it as Administrator?

Comment: yes, i did. the problem happen when I create a database connection. I will get a dialog with message like: "The program may be unstable, which could result in data loss. Decide how you want to proceed and click OK." the detailed exception as above.

Answer (score 0):

this caused by 3 files below missing, usually it will not happen

`src/META-INF/cwallet.sso
src/META-INF/cwallet.sso.lck
src/META-INF/jps-config.xml`

please also refer to https://community.oracle.com/thread/3870268?sr=stream